# "that" and "which" objective

Tags: grammar

Although the "that" and "which" are objective in the following sentences, why the writer has mentioned them?

> Students of general English will not have such specific needs, of
>   course, and so their lessons and the materials **which** the teachers
>   use will almost look different from those for students with more
>   clearly identifiable needs.

And

> During the war, people would eat all kinds of things **that** we don't
>   eat now.

Answer (score 1):

Because they could. In the first case, the writer almost certainly thought the sentence was clearer with *which* than it would have been without. In the second, probably just personal choice.

Comment: Generally speaking how can we judge a sentence is clearer with "which" and "that" objective?

Comment: If  sentence is long and complicated, it will probably be clearer with one of them than without,